# Robocopy syntax to copy single file in the same directory with new name?

Tags: windows, command-line, robocopy

I need to make a copy of a file:

1. with all the security (ACL) permissions - that's why I chose **robocopy**
2. the copy must be in the same directory with new name obviously

The Robocopy syntax is drastically different from any other command line tools and I don't even know if it is possible to acheive this with robocopy?

What I have tried is:

```
robocopy c:\temp\ c:temp\ file1.txt file2.txt
```

however this does not work since this is the sintax to copy the two files listed but since the source & destination are the same the command is ignored... I am not sure it is possible...

Comment: This could be a great learning experience for you, and very simply answered by trial and error. Instead you came looking for someone to write the command for you. It appears you haven't even tried.

Comment: it took me an hour of trial and error and I poisted the question because I am coming to the conclusion it is not possible...

Comment: Ok, but you haven't posted any information to show us how you were led to the conclusion this is not possible. You could've posted the various options and commands you tried and what results you achieved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Robocopy's primary use case is to mirror or migrate files from one path to a different path. It could be used to copy a single file to a different directory, but it does not rename files. Try the following powershell commands:

```
copy-item file1.txt file2.txt
get-acl file1.txt | set-acl file2.txt
```

Comment: Thanks - great suggestion; I'll give it a try and accept your answer if it works well. I shied away from using powershell as I found it very slow and sometimes unreliable with low level stuff like file permissions, because it is using mainly .net framework under the covers...

Answer (score 0):

xcopy can deal with it:

```
echo F|xcopy c:\temp\file1.txt c:\file2.txt /Y
```

**echo F** means (xcopy without asking file or directory,and choose file to pipe in xcopy command), and **/Y** is the parameter of overwriting the file.